# How can I set the certificates in CURL

Tags: curl, terminal, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

In order to get a successful response I am using `curl --cacert <path of ca.pem> ...` but how can i set the path of ca.pem in a configuration file in mac in order to not specify the path of the certificate every time, and i can directly use `curl ...`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

On your system you can set environment variables to point to these files.

Try:

```
export SSL_CERT_FILE=/path/to/ca.pem
```

There is also `SSL_CERT_DIR` environment variable to specify the directory containing certificates.

You can add this to your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` file to make this permanent.

This can be changed at compile time with curl by passing `--with-ca-path=DIRECTORY` when building curl but I'd recommend leaving it as is.

Better yet, find out what CA path/file your OS and/or OpenSSL are using and add the relevant certificate there.  I have no idea where they live on Mac but you should have a directory of trusted CA certs which curl is using for verification (probably somewhere in /etc).

Comment: I wonder if these "add up" or override each other. I have CA certs in a canonical location which is presumably being accessed but that bundle does not contain enough certs so I have an additional file. I'm not allowed to write to the bundle so I'd have to supply an additional path. Are `SSL_CERT_DIR` *and* `SSL_CERT_FILE` *both* checked, and are the additional locations checked as well as the canonical location?

Comment: If you add `--trace-ascii <tracefile>` to curl it will log your attempt in `<tracefile>` and include the path to the CA certs it's using, if you don't know where they are yet.

Comment: I guess you can just catenate all the readable certs into your own location anyway and just indicate that one to `curl`.

Answer (score 0):

If your curl version was not built with TLS backend `Schannel`, you can set the environment variable `CURL_CA_BUNDLE` to the path of your certificate file.

You can verify this by running `curl -V`. If the version string does not contain `Schannel` this answer applies to you.

Please note that if you have the certificate in your home folder, you should write the full path and not use `~`.

This works for me:
`export CURL_CA_BUNDLE="/Users/myuser/cert.crt"`

Source: [cURL documentation](https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html)