# Configure python to use same SSL certificates as wget?

Tags: python, python-requests, ssl-certificate, wget, detectron

While using `detectron2` I've ran into SSL issues.  However, it seems the SSL issues are related to python as they don't appear while using `wget`.

I can't use `detectron2` to download the weights file `https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/detectron2/COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x/137849600/model_final_f10217.pkl`:

```
from detectron2.config import get_cfg
from detectron2.engine import DefaultTrainer

cfg = get_cfg()
cfg.merge_from_file(model_zoo.get_config_file("COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x.yaml"))
cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS = model_zoo.get_checkpoint_url("COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x.yaml")

default_trainer = DefaultTrainer(cfg)
```

The above `detectron2` code gives the following error:

```
URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1091)>
```

I tried using `requests` which also didn't work:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/detectron2/COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x/137849600/model_final_f10217.pkl')
```

I can use wget to download the file:

```
wget https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/detectron2/COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x/137849600/model_final_f10217.pkl
```

How can I setup python to use the same SSL certificates that wget is using?

Comment: `requests` should bring in `certifi` which has root certs in it, probably roughly the same as what `wget` is using. Detectron has had some flakiness with their whole files downloading, so for your requests code, what if you tried to add `verify=False` to your request for an experiment?

Comment: @wkl using verify=False as argument to `requests.get` does work.  I should've mentioned I tried that.  However, I want to use SSL verification.  I think you're right that `requests` uses `certifi`, but it seems like whatever is done is using different certs than `wget` and `wget` works.  Re detectron flakiness, I heard about that.  But I don't think what would explain why this case since `wget` works, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Detectron’s files are served by multiple hosts on the backend so this could be a matter of poor configuration on some of them, and your requests are sometimes assigned to a bad server.  Notice that the error is complaining about a self signed cert which would indicate that one of their servers is using a self signed cert, and in that case you’d have to ignore verification, using different trusted certs wouldn’t matter. If this continues to be an issue, file a bug with the GitHub project.

Comment: Re "sometimes assigned to a bad server", I've been using detectron2 on a different computer and haven't seen this SSL issue.  If the problem was really sometimes requests being routed to a bad server, wouldn't I see this on both computers I use?  Also, wouldn't I see the problem with wget somtimes too?

Comment: Adding this link for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48949008/wget-where-does-it-look-for-certificates

Comment: Are you behind a corporate network or are otherwise getting MITM'ed? Why is there a self-signed certificate?

Comment: Actually the better answer than the one I have posted below is to use the variables described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38571099/how-can-i-set-the-certificates-in-curl: SSL_CERT_DIR or SSL_CERT_PATH.  Since I don't have the setup to test your problem directly, I can't honestly post this as an "answer", but try it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is not really demonstrating a reproducible error, so it won't be easy to help without knowing the specific details about your network configuration and certificate authority

Comment: instead of using verify=False, try using verify={cert_location_path}

Comment: `wget` works because it uses a complex detection mechanism to look for truststores. Maybe you can run `strace wget https://dl...` to see what files it is opening on your system.

Comment: strace to see what wget is doing is a great suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

I did run following testing using [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) which is part of standard library

```
import urllib.request
import ssl
with urllib.request.urlopen('https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/detectron2/COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x/137849600/model_final_f10217.pkl',context=ssl.SSLContext()) as f:
    content = f.read()
```

after that content is bytes object, no error or warning did appear during that. Please try running above code and write what is result in your case.

Comment: urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:997)>

Answer (score -1):

Set the REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE environment variable to point to your certificates bundle file.

I don't know if the requests package even tries to look in the standard system locations for your certificates, but I have seen that at least under RHEL7 it does not find them when tools like wget do.

Following @wim's comment, I did further digging into detectron2.  While the search they used to make their point doesn't actually prove that point (the actual request calls are handled by code in a separate facebookresearch repository), it appears that detectron2 is ultimately using urllib to make the actual https requests.

From some digging into the urllib documentation it should be defaulting to use the system certificates, so I am perplexed why this fails when wget succeeds.

However, using `export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`, or where ever your bundle file is (use `curl -v https://google.com 2>&1 | grep CAfile` to see), should allow you to use requests to pull the weights file local.  Then configuration could specify the local location and detectron2 would not need to make an https request at all.

Not a pretty solution, but it is a solution.

Comment: [detectron2 doesn't use requests](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Afacebookresearch%2Fdetectron2%20requests&type=code), so this answer is useless.

Comment: @wim, that search doesn't actually prove your point.  If you dig deeper you find that detectron2 uses the iopath.common.file_io PathManager (which is in a different repository) and only by digging through that code do you find that it is using urllib and not requests.  Still my answer should fix the broken requests call described in the question, and that can be used to get the file locally and thus solve the detectron2 problem by not requiring detectron2 to make an https request.

Answer (score -1):

I've test on my vps(in tencent cloud), the requests moduel works well. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Here is the log I'm runing on a fresh docker container, and it works well too, maybe you'll upgrade your system to latested, it would save your time.

```
➜  ~ docker run --rm -it python bash 
Unable to find image 'python:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/python
0a9573503463: Pull complete 
1ccc26d841b4: Pull complete 
800d84653581: Pull complete 
7c632e57ea62: Pull complete 
f9a1922eee8a: Pull complete 
7c45daddd450: Pull complete 
0952bd8ba4ec: Pull complete 
53f1aa318bc2: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:2586dd7abe015eeb6673bc66d18f0a628a997c293b41268bc981e826bc0b5a92
Status: Downloaded newer image for python:latest
root@37c7f698f922:/# pip3 install ^C
root@37c7f698f922:/# pip3 install requests
Collecting requests
  Obtaining dependency information for requests from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/70/8e/0e2d847013cb52cd35b38c009bb167a1a26b2ce6cd6965bf26b47bc0bf44/requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  Downloading requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.6 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer<4,>=2 (from requests)
  Obtaining dependency information for charset-normalizer<4,>=2 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/93/6d/63027361182c26155517ed010a05d73528511f45faab2047a014e69c4651/charset_normalizer-3.3.1-cp312-cp312-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata
  Downloading charset_normalizer-3.3.1-cp312-cp312-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (33 kB)
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5 (from requests)
  Downloading idna-3.4-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 61.5/61.5 kB 3.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 (from requests)
  Obtaining dependency information for urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d2/b2/b157855192a68541a91ba7b2bbcb91f1b4faa51f8bae38d8005c034be524/urllib3-2.0.7-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  Downloading urllib3-2.0.7-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.6 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests)
  Obtaining dependency information for certifi>=2017.4.17 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4c/dd/2234eab22353ffc7d94e8d13177aaa050113286e93e7b40eae01fbf7c3d9/certifi-2023.7.22-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  Downloading certifi-2023.7.22-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
Downloading requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 62.6/62.6 kB 9.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading certifi-2023.7.22-py3-none-any.whl (158 kB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 158.3/158.3 kB 19.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading charset_normalizer-3.3.1-cp312-cp312-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (139 kB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 139.1/139.1 kB 16.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading urllib3-2.0.7-py3-none-any.whl (124 kB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 124.2/124.2 kB 14.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: urllib3, idna, charset-normalizer, certifi, requests
Successfully installed certifi-2023.7.22 charset-normalizer-3.3.1 idna-3.4 requests-2.31.0 urllib3-2.0.7
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.2.1 -> 23.3.1
[notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
root@37c7f698f922:/# python3
Python 3.12.0 (main, Oct 12 2023, 09:45:59) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.head('https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/detectron2/COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x/137849600/model_final_f10217.pkl')
>>> response.headers
{'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream', 'Content-Length': '177841981', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-amz-id-2': 'vnl0jZkm3ByQAhZwO4hzA93i/kDtG7ctciJZIsHiYEKhv4Tz62U9Kfd5Lo68tE/3rYHkffTmpvI=', 'x-amz-request-id': 'PKPJKJSDM33RQM28', 'Date': 'Tue, 24 Oct 2023 09:44:14 GMT', 'Last-Modified': 'Fri, 20 Sep 2019 21:42:43 GMT', 'ETag': '"26f204b1a2f8a65e6047a1d632023d9e-12"', 'x-amz-server-side-encryption': 'AES256', 'x-amz-meta-s3cmd-attrs': 'atime:1568969096/ctime:1568969182/gid:1185200050/gname:yuxinwu/md5:f10217d075016156e04f19242e20d8d8/mode:33188/mtime:1568969181/uid:1185200050/uname:yuxinwu', 'x-amz-version-id': 'vb7OV8Y.ATPYnyZy01wuxis9UbeAXb2c', 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'Server': 'AmazonS3', 'X-Cache': 'Hit from cloudfront', 'Via': '1.1 30e954298424aa69c035e25834574742.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)', 'X-Amz-Cf-Pop': 'FRA56-P4', 'X-Amz-Cf-Id': 'UP83O1tETvBouF-6sSYBnluTVD7aVKYF2_lPKc85YGOcQ9UJ3KFjzg==', 'Age': '323'}
```

Comment: It is generally not useful to post some "unable to reproduce" info as an answer. Usually that should be a comment and/or a close-vote.

Comment: got it, thank so much